# datetime to DateTimePicker VB.Net in Long format and vice versa

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, date, windows-forms-designer

Is it even possible to save the value of DateTimePicker (Long format) to datetime (database). Then do the reverse from datetime (datebase) set to DateTimePicker. Do we have a simpler code for this?

I am using MySQL in VB.Net Windows Form.

here's my code in vb.net:

```
'" & date1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & " " & date1_time.Value.ToString("hh:mm:ss") & "." & Now.Millisecond & "'
```

in MySQL:
date1 datetime

Comment: Why not use the same format for the picker internals that you use for the database. This doesn't have to be what the end-user sees. The transition can be handled in application code or JavaScript

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean a Windows Forms `DateTimePicker` but you need to specify.  ALWAYS provide tags for technology as well as language, e.g. Windows Forms or Web Forms or jQuery, etc.

Comment: If it is WinForms, there's absolutely no reason or even justification for converting the `DateTime` value you have to a `String`.  You get it from the database as a `DateTime` and you put it into the control as a `DateTime`, then you get it back from the control as a `DateTime` and send it back tot he database as a `DateTime`.  The only place text is involved is when the control displays the value to the user, so not your concern beyond setting the appropriate properties of the control.  The `Value` property is type `DateTime` so format is irrelevant.

Comment: im sorry about that....  and yes.. I mean windows form in vb,net

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are talking about a Windows Forms `DateTimePicker`, there's nothing do.  The `Format` and `CustomFormat` properties of the control only determine how the data is displayed.  The `Value` property is still type `DateTime` and that has no format.  It's just a number.  When you save to the database, you save that `DateTime` value and it gets - or at least, it should get - stored in the database in its native date/time data type too, so format is again a non-issue.  In MySQL, you should generally be using the `DATE` data type for dates without a time portion or `DATETIME` for values with both date and time.  At no point should you ever convert the values to text yourself in this whole process.  That part is handled by the `DateTimePicker` control.

If you're using an appropriate data type in the database as it sounds like you are, then you will be getting a `DateTime` from the database.  You just assign that directly to the value property, e.g.

```
myDateTimePicker.Value = CDate(myDataRow("MyColumn"))
```

or:

```
myDateTimePicker.Value = myDataReader.GetDateTime(myDataReader.GetOrdinal("MyColumn"))
```

To save the data back to the database, you simply create a parameter on your command in the same way as you would for any other data, then assign the `DateTime` to the `Value` of that parameter, e.g.

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@MyColumn", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myDateTimePicker.Value
```

If you don't know how parameters work, look that up now as it is the ONLY acceptable way to insert variables into SQL code.

Comment: yes.... I  mean windows form.. do we have a simpler way to save the date in database then do the reverse...  im having trouble by setting the datetime to datetimepicker

Comment: The reason you're having an issue is that you're doing exactly what I told you not to do, i.e. creating a `String`.  **DO NOT** create a `String`.  I'll add some small code examples to my answer.

Comment: ty bro... I get it... :)